# I am unable to install gcc in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started from scratch in order to install gromacs in my system (Windows), but my Ubuntu does not install gcc.

[image: gcc error in Ubuntu]

Comment: `gcc` is already installed. So the question doesn't make any sense. Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: The message explicitly states that `gcc` is already installed, but that `sse4.2-support` is not installed.

Comment: And the message also suggests how to fix the dependency issue.

Comment: In future, please copy-paste the terminal output as text, and don't put screenshots of terminal outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `gcc` is already installed, but another package has missing dependencies.

Run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to fix the issue, as the terminal output suggests.